# Threshold an image for a given range and Sobel kernel

Tags: python, performance, object-oriented, image

The class defines functions to threshold an image for a given range and Sobel kernel. Each function has similarities, i.e. they share the same following tasks:

- each function converts an image to grayscale
- take the gradient
- rescale to 8 bit
- apply a threshold, and create a binary image result

```
class GRADIENT_THRESHOLD(object):
    '''
    Define functions to threshold an image for a given range and Sobel kernel
    '''

    def __init__(self, args):
        self.args = args

    def gradient_abs_sobel(self, img, orient='x', sobel_kernel=3, thresh=(0, 255)):
        # convert to grayscale
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        # take the absolute value of the gradient in given orient = 'x' or 'y'
        if orient == 'x':
            abs_sobel = np.absolute(cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0))
        if orient == 'y':
            abs_sobel = np.absolute(cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1))
        # scale to 8-bit (0 - 255) then convert to type = np.uint8
        scaled_sobel = np.uint8(255*abs_sobel/np.max(abs_sobel))
        # create a mask of 1's where the scaled gradient magnitude
        # is > thresh_min and < thresh_max
        binary_output = np.zeros_like(scaled_sobel)
        # return this mask as your binary_output image
        binary_output[(scaled_sobel >= thresh[0]) & (scaled_sobel <= thresh[1])] = 1
        # return the binary image
        return binary_output 

    def gradient_magnitude(self, img, sobel_kernel=3, thresh=(0, 255)):
        # convert to grayscale
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        # take both Sobel x and y gradients
        sobelx = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=sobel_kernel)
        sobely = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=sobel_kernel)
        # calculate the gradient magnitude
        gradmag = np.sqrt(sobelx**2 + sobely**2)
        # rescale to 8 bit
        scale_factor = np.max(gradmag)/255 
        gradmag = (gradmag/scale_factor).astype(np.uint8) 
        # create a binary image of ones where threshold is met, zeros otherwise
        binary_output = np.zeros_like(gradmag)
        binary_output[(gradmag >= thresh[0]) & (gradmag <= thresh[1])] = 1
        # return the binary image
        return binary_output


    # Define a function to threshold an image for a given range and Sobel kernel
    def gradient_direction(self, img, sobel_kernel=3, thresh=(0, np.pi/2)):
        # convert to grayscale
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        # take both Sobel x and y gradients
        sobelx = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=sobel_kernel)
        sobely = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=sobel_kernel)
        # take the absolute value of the gradient direction
        absgraddir = np.arctan2(np.absolute(sobely), np.absolute(sobelx))
        # apply a threshold, and create a binary image result
        binary_output =  np.zeros_like(absgraddir)
        binary_output[(absgraddir >= thresh[0]) & (absgraddir <= thresh[1])] = 1
        # return the binary image
        return binary_output
```

Comment: in `gradient_direction` I see no scaling. Is this intentional?

Comment: @MaartenFabré, yes, it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as things are now, there is little use for the class in this case. the `self` argument is never used in the functions.

This is easily factored into different functions

```
def grayscale(img):
    return cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

Whether this deserves a separate function or can be inlined is your choice. If you need to type this a lot, or if the method of grayscaling can change in the future, it will be easier to put it in a separate method.. You could also move the colorspace to the arguments to make this more versatile and also accept HSV or Luv encoded images.

```
def sobel_xy(gray, sobel_kernel=3, absolute=True):
    sobel_x = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=sobel_kernel)
    sobel_y = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=sobel_kernel)
    if absolute:
        sobel_x, sobel_y = np.absolute(sobel_x), np.absolute(sobel_y)
    return sobel_x, sobel_y
```

This calculation is done in all methods, so refactoring it is simple and effective

```
def gradient_magnitude(gray, sobel_kernel=3):
    return np.hypot(*sobel_xy(gray, sobel_kernel))

def gradient_direction(gray, sobel_kernel=3):
    return np.arctan2(*sobel_xy(gray, sobel_kernel))
```

This part is pretty straightforward. All I changed was use `np.hypot` to calculate the magnitude

```
def gradient_abs_sobel(gray, orient='x'):
    dx, dy = (1, 0) if orient == 'x' else (0, 1)
    sobel = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, dx, dy)
    return np.absolute(sobel)

def gradient_abs_sobel2(gray, orient='x'):
    orientation = {'x': 0,'y': 1}[orient]
    sobel = sobel_xy(gray)
    return sobel[orientation]
```

Depending on taste and the expense of the `sobel` calculation you can pick either of the 2

```
def scale(sobel, MAX=255, dtype=np.uint8):
    return dtype(MAX * sobel / np.max(sobel))

def mask(img, lower, upper):
    return (img >= lower) & (img <= upper)
```

Are pretty straightforward too. Instead of the `np.zeros_like` you can directly use the boolean array of the comparison

Now instead of calling 1 function, you just call the 4 elements subsequently. If this is too much work you can still make 1 compound method for the 3 cases.

```
gray = grayscale(img)
abs_sobel = gradient_abs_sobel(gray)
result = mask(scale(abs_sobel), 10, 130)
```

Comment: @Maarten Fabré, thank you for your feedback!! I particularly enjoyed the two following lines and the way you cut the code: lines = { 1 : ' dx, dy = (1, 0) if orient == 'x' else (0, 1) ' ; 2 : ' orientation = {'x': 0,'y': 1}[orient] '}

Answer (score 0):

Thank to Maarten Fabré's feedbacks, I have rewritten the  code as the following:

```
def grayscale(image):
    return cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

def sobel_xy(gray, sobel_kernel=9, absolute=True):
    sobel_x = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=sobel_kernel)
    sobel_y = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=sobel_kernel)
    if absolute:
        sobel_x, sobel_y = np.absolute(sobel_x), np.absolute(sobel_y)
    return sobel_x, sobel_y

def sobel_abs(gray, orient='x'):
    orientation = {'x': 0,'y': 1}[orient]
    sobel       = sobel_xy(gray)
    return sobel[orientation]

def scale(sobel, MAX=255, dtype=np.uint8):
    return dtype(MAX * sobel / np.max(sobel))

def mask(image, lower, upper):
    return (image >= lower) & (image <= upper)

def gradient_abs_sobel(image, orient='x', thresh=(0, 255)):
    gray  = grayscale(image)
    sobel = sobel_abs(gray, orient=orient)
    sobel_scale = scale(sobel, MAX=thresh[1], dtype=np.uint8)
    return mask(sobel_scale, thresh[0], thresh[1])

def gradient_magnitude(image, sobel_kernel=9, thresh=(0, 255)):
    gray    = grayscale(image)
    gradmag = np.hypot(*sobel_xy(gray, sobel_kernel=sobel_kernel, absolute=False))
    gradmag = scale(gradmag, MAX=thresh[1], dtype=np.uint8)
    return mask(gradmag, thresh[0], thresh[1])

def gradient_direction(image, sobel_kernel=15, thresh=(0, np.pi/2)): # thresh=(0.7, 1.3)
    gray       = grayscale(image)
    absgraddir = np.arctan2(*sobel_xy(gray, sobel_kernel=sobel_kernel, absolute=True))
    return mask(absgraddir, thresh[0], thresh[1])


def main():
    # parameters and placeholders
    args = PARSE_ARGS()
    # Choose a Sobel kernel size
    ksize = 9
    # Read images
    image        = mpimg.imread(args.sand+'signs_vehicles_xygrad.jpg')
    img_solution = mpimg.imread(args.sand+'binary-combo-example.jpg')
    # Apply each of the thresholding functions
    gradx = gradient_sobel_abs(image, orient='x', sobel_kernel=ksize, thresh=(20, 100))
    grady = gradient_sobel_abs(image, orient='y', sobel_kernel=ksize, thresh=(20, 100))
    mag_binary = gradient_magnitude(image, sobel_kernel=ksize, thresh=(20, 100))
    dir_binary = gradient_direction(image, sobel_kernel=15, thresh=(0.7, 1.3))

    # combine thresholds
    combined1, combined2, combined3 = np.zeros_like(dir_binary), np.zeros_like(dir_binary), np.zeros_like(dir_binary)
    combined1[((gradx == 1) & (grady == 1)) | ((mag_binary == 1) & (dir_binary == 1))] = 1
    combined2[((gradx == 1) & (grady == 1))] = 1
    combined3[((mag_binary == 1) & (dir_binary == 1))] = 1

    # Plot the result
    row, column = [5, 2]
    figure, axes = plt.subplots(row, column, figsize=(15, 20))
    figure.tight_layout()
    list_title_image = [['Original Image',image],
                        ['Expected result', img_solution],
                        ['gradx', gradx],
                        ['grady', grady],
                        ['mag_binary', mag_binary],
                        ['dir_binary', dir_binary],                        
                        ['combined1', combined1],
                        ['combined2', combined2],
                        ['combined3', combined3],
                        ['Original Image', image] ]

    for ax, img in zip(axes.flatten(), list_title_image):
        ax.imshow(img[1], cmap='gray')
        ax.set_title(img[0], fontsize=15)
        ax.axis('off')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I would replace the `thresh[0], thresh[1]` by `*thresh`, or change the arguments of `mask` from `lower, upper` to `thresh`

Comment: It's nice that you posted the updated code, but you should accept Maarten's answer, as it helped you. This will give Maarten the rep he deserves.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, done :) Bear with me, I am quite new on this platform.